# Data structure for One column list for storing addresses , better lookup O(1) in C++

Tags: c++, performance, dynamic, data-structures, lookup

I am a beginner in C++. I need to store list of addresses that give a very good performance in terms of lookup and adding new entries.

I first want to see if the address tis already present in the list, if yes , then don't write, else add new entry to that list.

And at the time of certain operation, look if the address is present in the list or not.

Is there any fast access and dynamic growing data structure in terms of memory and space in C++.

Comment: You might find the new [unordered types in C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) useful. They are almost identical to std::set, std::map except rather than trees, they use hash tables. If you need them in older versions of the standard, they are in [Boost.Unordered] (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/unordered.html) and are just as good as what is in the new standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) (usually implemented as some [red-black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree)) which has a logarithmic complexity so should be enough in practice.

If you had a C++11 standard conforming implementation, you could consider [`std::unordered_map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/unordered_map/) (usually implemented as some [hash-table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)).

If you don't need any associated data to keys, but just to handle sets of them, considuer `std::set` or `std::unordered_set`

And many libraries (Boost, Qt, ...) also implement associative containers.

Comment: You can use `boost::unordered_map` in C++03.

Comment: But Boost is not standard, even if it is widely available. Some people might want to avoid it.

Comment: Avoiding Boost is silly and counter-productive. `std::unordered_map` is pretty much lifted from Boost, and the Boost implementation is probably fairly stand-alone and can be copied into the project if someone doesn't dependency on full Boost package.

Comment: @Basile: That's those people's problems, not the problem of the Internet at large.

Comment: @Basil, Thanks for the suggestion. Would you please explain me what's the performance difference in C++ std: map  and std::unordered map? and std::unordered set? What advantage will i get using unordered set.

Comment: @Basmah: A good C++ book or site would explain much better or faster than I do.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [boost::unordered_map](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html).